# Assign x:Name property to a checkbox in source code [Xamarin/C#]

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Hello I have set of check boxes that are generated from source code and not in XAML. Now, I wanted to set x:Name during creation of it so that I can loop through each element using the FindByName. I planned on setting name like checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3...

So that I can use this FindByName

```
        foreach (var  qaItem in question.Entity.QuestionAnswer)
        {
            (FindByName($"checkbox{qaItem.OrderNum}") as CheckBox).IsChecked = false;
        }
```

Is there a way to set "x:Name" in source? since the number of checkboxes is not definite.

Comment: `x:Name` is not actually a property, it is just a XAML helper that is used to create a C# variable name.  If you are creating the elements at runtime, you need to maintain an array or list in order to keep track of them

Comment: Do you have any idea how to loop through elements created in source?

Comment: I just told you that you need to maintain a list as you create them

Comment: My main problem really is to give a set of checkboxes a single selection capability only. I know that radio button would be a best answer, but I need to comply with client's requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x:Name` is not actually a property, it is just a XAML helper that is used to create a C# variable name. If you are creating the elements at runtime, you need to maintain an array or list in order to keep track of them

you could do something like this

```
Dictionary<string,Checkbox> myCheckboxList = new Dictionary<string,Checkbox>();
```

then as you create each checbox

```
var cb = new Checkbox();
... set properties, etc ...
myCheckboxList.Add(qaItem.OrderNum, cb);
```