# I’m using MAUI and C#. How do I set x:name of a checkbox in the code-behind?

Tags: c#, xaml, code-behind, maui

I am dynamically creating a list of checkboxes in the code-behind, based on the files I have in a specified directory.

I wish the set the x:Name of the checkbox to the name of its associated file or their associated GUID.
How do I do this?

Pseudocode for the desired effect:

```
List<string> selected;
```

#### Code-behind

```
private function(string directoryfolder){
  var folder = Directory.GetFiles(directoryfolder,...);
  for (file in folder){
    checkbox chckbx = new CheckBox();
    chckbx.Name = file #THIS IS THE PART I CANT GET TO WORK
    chckbx.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler<CheckedChangedEventArgs>(CheckBox_Changed);
    HorizantalStackInXAML.Add(chckbx)
  }
}

private void CheckBox_Changed(object sender, ...){
  if(sender.Name in selected){
    selected.Remove(sender.Name);
  }else{
    selected.Add(sender.Name);
  }
}
```

Attempts:

I’ve tried to set the name like so:

```
chckbx.SetValue(FrameworkElement.NameProperty,user.GUID+"-select");
```

But I get the error that

> reference to type 'DependencyProperty' claims it is defined in 'windowbase', but it could not be found

Comment: you can't.  `x:Name` is a XAML helper, not a "real" C# property.  If you want to track dynamically created objects, you will need to use a data structure to do it, like a `Dictionary<string,object>`

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72121469/assign-xname-property-to-a-checkbox-in-source-code-xamarin-c